# Pasar argumentos a un metodo

Tags: java, backend, parametros

tengo una consulta básica, tengo una  clase Email la cual cree porque enviaba muchos parámetros en mi método sendEmail así que los puso en un Bean

```
public class Email implements Serializable {
    public String name ;
    public String holder;
    public String paciente;
    public String seguro;
    public String monto;
    public String Dni;
***Getters and St ***
```

Entonces uso mi Bean y la uso substituyendo los parámetros que enviaba antes

```
  @Override
    public Boolean  sendEmail(Email email) {
        JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
        requestParam.put(NOMBRE, email.name);
        requestParam.put(TITULAR, email.holder);
        requestParam.put(PACIENTE, email.paciente);
        requestParam.put(SEGURO_CONTRATADO, email.seguro);
        requestParam.put(MONTO_PRESENTADO, email.monto);
        requestParam.put(DNI_TITULAR, email.Dni);
```

Ahora quiero usar ese método sendEmail  pero Como uso mi método sendEmail en mi método de enviarCorreo si este tiene más de un parámetro , antes usaba 6 parámetros y ahora lo convertí a solo 1.

```
 @Override
    public Boolean enviarCorreo(String userIdentity, List<String> documents) {
        UserIdentity userIdentityInfo = userProfileOperation.getUserProfile(userIdentity);
        EmailProperties.EmailHeader returnedHeader = emailProperties.getReturned();
        ReturnedEmailContext returnedEmailContext = new ReturnedEmailContext(userIdentityInfo, documents);
        sendEmail( " AQUÍ QUIERO ENVIAR LOS PARÁMETROS DE enviarCorreo pero son más de 1");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: ¿dentro de enviarCorreo() como obtenias los valores que enviabas en sendEmail() ?

Comment: sendEmail tenía 6 argumentos string y solo los reemplazaba porque tambien eran string :
sendEmail (userIdentityInfo.getName(), nombrecompleto, paciente, poliza, monto, userIdentityInfo.getDocumentId())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente una observación, aquí deberías usar los getter´s para obtener los valores de las propiedades del objeto

```
  @Override
    public Boolean  sendEmail(Email email) {
        JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
        requestParam.put(NOMBRE, email.getName()/*email.name*/);
        requestParam.put(TITULAR, email.getHolder()/*email.holder*/);
        requestParam.put(PACIENTE, email.getPaciente()/*email.paciente*/);
        requestParam.put(SEGURO_CONTRATADO, email.getSeguro()/*email.seguro*/);
        requestParam.put(MONTO_PRESENTADO, email.getMonto()/*email.monto*/);
        requestParam.put(DNI_TITULAR, email.getDni()/*email.Dni*/);
```

Ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta, aquí debes crear un objeto para enviar el objeto a el método `sendEmail()` :

```
 @Override
    public Boolean enviarCorreo(String userIdentity, List<String> documents) {
        ...
        ...
        //Crea instancia de objeto y agrega valores a sus propiedades
        Email email = new Email();
        email.setName(...);
        email.setHolder(...); 
        email.setPaciente(...); 
        ...
        ....
        //Envia objeto email creado a método sendEmail().
        sendEmail(email);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias! Funcionó

Comment: Excelente @CoraVP , saludos.